# download part of gzipped text file

Tags: curl, split, gzip

I have some large gzipped text files on an FTP server, that get updated regularly, ie. lines are added to the text files and then are gzipped again. Is there any way to access those new lines without having to download the new .gz each time it is updated?

My extremely naive try was

```
curl -o part_of_file.gz -r0-10000,-10000 ftp.<source>/file.gz
```

to download the first 10000 bytes (in case there is a header) and the last 10000 for the data I'm interested in, but, without much surprise gunzip gives an "unexpected end of file" error so apparently gzip does not work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You need to decompress all of the data in a gzip file in order to get the uncompressed data at the end.